# android downloading two files on single click and share their progress in single progressbar

Tags: android, download, progress-bar, share

I am getting some audio files from url and their subtitles mapped with them.now i wants to download that .mp3 file & .srt file on click of download button, also that they should share same progress bar and show the total progress in the same.
And they should save in two different directories of sdcard. I have implemented the single file download with progress bar. any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Update: Answer for all those are still in search of this kind...

```
    String strGetFName;
    String strVipEpub;

    public DownloadFile()
    {
        strGetFName = getFilename();
        strVipEpub = getVipLessonEpubFilename();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl) 
    {
        try 
        {
            URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
            URL urlePub = new URL(sUrl[1]);
            Log.e("urls"," "+sUrl[0]+","+sUrl[1]);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            URLConnection connectionePub = urlePub.openConnection();
            Log.e("connection","done");
            connection.connect();
            connectionePub.connect();
            Log.e("connection","Connected");
            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
            int fileLengthePub = connectionePub.getContentLength();
            Log.e("fileLength"," "+fileLength);
            int bytesFromMP3 = fileLength;
            int bytesFromSubtitle = fileLengthePub;
            int totalBytesToDownload = bytesFromMP3 + bytesFromSubtitle;
            Log.e("bytesFromMP3"," "+bytesFromMP3);
            Log.e("bytesFromSubtitle"," "+bytesFromSubtitle);
            Log.e("total"," "+totalBytesToDownload);

            int bytesDownloadedSoFar = 0;
            while(bytesDownloadedSoFar <= bytesFromSubtitle)
            {
                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlePub.openStream());

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strVipEpub);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) 
                {
                    total += count;
                    bytesDownloadedSoFar += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (bytesDownloadedSoFar * 100 / totalBytesToDownload));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
            while(bytesDownloadedSoFar <= bytesFromMP3)
            {
                // download the file
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strGetFName);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) 
                {
                    total += count;
                    bytesDownloadedSoFar += count;
                    // publishing the progress....
                    publishProgress((int) (bytesDownloadedSoFar * 100 / totalBytesToDownload));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }

                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("File"," Not Downloaded"+e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
        pbDownloading.setProgress(progress[0]);
        tvProgress.setText(progress[0].toString()+"%");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Log.e("is ","Downloading complete");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Downloading Multiple Files**

If you have single download working, it should really be as simple as duplicating the code and changing it to download the .srt file. You can set them to download one after another if you setup an AsyncTask.

**Combining The Progress Bar Status**

For this, I'm guessing that before you start the download for either file, you need to get the size of each file. Set the progress bar to the summation of the two sizes, then as you download update the progress bar with the number of bytes downloaded. The current download value would have to continue when you download the next file.

Below is some very *rough* pseudo code. I have no idea how you're downloading the file and how you are threading it (hopefully it's something like an AsyncTask). Below is just the logic I would apply. If you show us your code so far, we can be more specific.

```
int bytesFromMP3 = GetSizeOfFileAtURL(urlOfMP3File);
int bytesFromSubtitle = GetSizeOfFileAtURL(urlOfSubtitlesFile);
int totalBytesToDownload = bytesFromMP3 + bytesFromSubtitle;

progressBar.setMax(totalBytesToDownload);

int bytesDownloadedSoFar = 0;

//Start some loop to download the MP3 File
while(...) 
{
    //Download some data from the MP3 File
    ...

    //Update the number of bytes downloaded based on the size of the chunk you just downloaded
    bytesDownloadedSoFar += sizeOfChunkJustDownloaded

    //Update the progress bar
    progressBar.setProgress(bytesDownloadedSoFar);
}

//Repeat the loop, but this time download the subtitle info. Don't reset bytesDownloadedSoFar, just continue to add to it. 
while(...)
```

Comment: that is working now i have implemented your idea and it became working for me...Thanks

Comment: @Gophermofur can you please tell how to do the same using phonegap android here is the code http://stackoverflow.com/q/20510524/2307391